# Custom Plugin Won't Work

Tags: plugin, custom-classes

I'm trying to create a class in EE, but for some reason it just won't work for me.
I've even went as far as making it as easy as possible, but I always get:

The following tag has a syntax error:

{exp:my_class_name:testfunction}

Please correct the syntax in your template.

Here's the simple class:

```
class My_class_name {

    public $return_data;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->EE =& get_instance();
    }

    public static function usage(){
        ob_start();
        ?>
        Coming Soon, this is just filler for now.
        <?php
        $buffer = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $buffer;
    }

    public function testfunction(){
        $this->return_data = ee()->TMPL->tagdata;
    }

}
```

and usage:

```
    {exp:my_class_name:testfunction}
    hey
    {/exp:my_class_name:testfunction}
```

Comment: can u see your plugin in CP plugin list ?

Comment: BTW: "$this->EE =& get_instance();" is redundant now as you're using the super global ee()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plugin class method needs to **return the (parsed) tagdata** instead of setting the `$this->return_data` property. The latter is only needed if the class constructor is used for template output. So:

```
public function testfunction()
{
    return ee()->TMPL->tagdata;
}
```